# giving an EJB a JNDI

Tags: glassfish, ejb, jndi

I have created and EJB with a remote interface:

```
@Stateless
public class TestSessionBean implements TestSessionRemote 
{

    public void businessMethod() 
    {
            System.out.println ("***businessMethod");
    }
}
```

I to access it from another component (e.g a servlet) running on the server via:

```
ic = new InitialContext();
ic.lookup("myEJB");
```

I am using netBeans 6.5.1 and glassfish v2.

How can I do that?

Thanks,
Ido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually ejb3 use a default naming convention, wich i've not found a way to get around.

The name for your bean would be something like:
TestSessionBean#package.TestSessionBean

To acess your remote service you can do something like this

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
ctx.lookup(interfaceClass.getSimpleName()+"#"+interfaceClass.getName());
```

where interfaceClass is the class of your remote interface.

do note you havent defined a remote interface(or local for that matter) for that webserver. you mightnot be able to acess theejb from another context.

As for changing the name that is actually i dont think is possible through anotations. not sure though

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting this almost a month later.  In Glassfish v2 you can do @Stateless(mappedName="fooBean") and then you're able to look up using "fooBean".  This is vendor-specific -- it is not portable.  Be careful though, because in Glassfish 3 (EJB 3.1) this changes some.  You can still use the mappedName with Remote interface lookup, but there is now a standardized java:global naming setup.  See http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html if you're not confused enough yet.