# Lookup EJB using InitialContext on Weblogic 10.x.x

Tags: java, ejb, weblogic, lookup, initial-context

Could you please tell me how to lookup EJB on Weblogic?
I have following bean:

```
@Stateless
@EJB(name = "DataAccess", beanInterface = DataAccessLocal.class)
public class DataAccess implements DataAccessLocal {
    ...
}
```

I need this bean in other class which is not part of managed content (just simple class), so I guess it should be done like this:

```
DataAccessLocal dataAccess = DataAccessLocal.class.cast((new InitialContext()).lookup("%SOME_JNDI_NAME%"));
```

The question is what should be used as %SOME_JNDI_NAME% in case of Weblogic 10.x.x AS?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I've answered this in another place: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676926/giving-an-ejb-a-jndi/677008#677008

Comment: Thanks @Nuno. Does it work for remote interface only? Or local too?

Comment: Not sure on that one, since i've been working with remote interfaces only

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would update your EJB class to look like this:

```
@Stateless(name="DataAccessBean", mappedName="ejb/DataAccessBean")
@Remote(DataAccessRemote.class)
@Local(DataAccessLocal.class)
public class DataAccess implements DataAccessLocal, DataAccessRemote {
    ...
}
```

Looking up the EJB from a class deployed in the same EAR (using the local interface):

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(); //if not in WebLogic container then you need to add URL and credentials.
// use <MAPPED_NAME>
Objet obj = ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/DataAccessBean");
```

EJB injection is usually preferred, and you can do it as follows:

```
@EJB(name="DataAccessBean")
DataAccessLocal myDataAccessBean;
```

If you are trying to use the EJB remotely then you will need to use the remote interface and the following JNDI name:

```
DataAccessBean#<package>.DataAccessRemote
```

Comment: Thank you @Jeff, I've just tried it out (with local interface) and got following exception: (I don't have full stacktrace but the main part is) "remaining name: env/ejb/DataAccessBean". Do you have any ideas?

Comment: happy to help via email - jeffrey.west@oracle.com.  We can post the solution here when we are done...

Comment: Also, if you are trying to access the EJB from outside the EAR where the EJB is deployed, or if the EJB is deployed in its own ejb-jar you will need to sue the remote method.

Comment: thank you. So far usage of remote interface is enought for me,but that's strange cause I make a call from the same EAR. If you will have any ideas about the problem, it could be nice if you let me know.

Comment: The generated JNDI name only works with the remote interface class. The local interface is not added to JNDI in WebLogic 10.3.x. I describe this at more length [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094427/publishing-ejbs-local-interface-in-weblogic/16031914#16031914)